# vector issue, C++ not sure what i've done wrong

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, object, vector

Ok so i'm fairly new to c++ and this is my first try using vectors. My goal is to store objects into a vector. I'm trying to follow this youtube tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPlW5tSUOUM

and i think mine is pretty much the same apart from his runs.

I just keep getting errors and it won't run. Any help would be appreciated :)
Maybe it's something small, but i've been checking for a while now and i can't see anything.

Errors:
1>c:\users\user\desktop\vector objects c++\testvectorobjects\testvectorobjects\main.cpp(61): error C3867: 'Employees::getSalary': function call missing argument list; use '&Employees::getSalary' to create a pointer to member

1>c:\users\user\desktop\vector objects c++\testvectorobjects\testvectorobjects\main.cpp(61): error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\ostream(695): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'

I have 3 files: main.cpp, Employee.h, Employees.cpp

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Employee.h"

void fillVector(vector<Employees>&);
//fill vector - fills in Employee Info
//vector<Employees>& - Employees at the station
void printVector(const vector<Employees>&);
//print vector - prints the employee info
//const vector<Employees>& - employees at the station

using namespace std;

    vector<Employees> Staff;


int main(){

    fillVector(Staff);
    printVector(Staff);

}


//filling the employee vector
void fillVector(vector<Employees> & newStaff){

    int id;
    double salary;
    string name;

    cout << "Number of Employees" << endl;
    int amountEmployees;
    cin >> amountEmployees;

    for (int i = 0; i < amountEmployees; i++) {
        cout << "Enter Employee Id: ";
        cin >> id;
        cout << "Enter Employee Salary: ";
        cin >> salary;
        cout << "Enter Employee Name: ";
        cin >> name;

        Employees newEmployees(id, salary, name);
        newStaff.push_back(newEmployees);
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

//printing the employee vector
void printVector(const vector<Employees>& newStaff){

    unsigned int size = newStaff.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Employee Id: " << newStaff[i].getID << endl;
        cout << "Employee Name: " << newStaff[i].getName << end;
        cout << "Employee Salary: " << newStaff[i].getSalary << end;
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

//Employee.h

```
//Header

#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employees{

    public:
        //after
        //Default Constructor
        Employees();

        //Overload constructor
        Employees(int, double, string);

        //Destructor
        ~Employees();

        //Accessor Functions
        int getID() const;
        //getId
        //return int - Id for Employee
        double getSalary() const;
        //getSalary
        //return salary - salary of Employee
        string getName() const;
        //getName 
        //return name - Name of Employee

        //Mutators
        void setId(int);
        //setId - for Employee

        void setSalary(double);
        //setSalary - for Employee

        void setName(string);
        //setName - for Employee
        //

        //before
        //ID
        //void setEmployeeId(int a){
        //employeeId = a;
        //} 
        ////Salary
        //void setSalary(double b){
        //salary = b;
        //}
        ////Name
        //void setName(string c){
        //name = c;
        //}
    private:
        //after
        //before
        int employeeId; //id
        double employeeSalary; //salary
        string employeeName; //name
};


#endif
```

//Employees.cpp

```
#include "Employee.h"


Employees::Employees() {
    employeeName = ' ';
}

Employees::Employees(int id, double salary, string name){
    employeeId = id;
    employeeSalary = salary;
    employeeName = name;
}

Employees::~Employees(){

}

int Employees::getID()const{
    return employeeId;
}

double Employees::getSalary()const{
    return employeeSalary;
}

string Employees::getName()const{
    return employeeName;
}

void Employees::setId(int id){
    employeeId = id;
}

void Employees::setSalary(double salary){
    employeeSalary = salary;
}

void Employees::setName(string name){
    employeeName = name;
}
```

Comment: Always read the error messages, multiple times if needed. And take a close look at the lines referenced (in your case line 61).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 'Employees::getSalary': function call missing argument list;
```

That seems quite clear: `getSalary` is a function, and you need an argument list when you call a function:

```
cout << "Employee Salary: " << newStaff[i].getSalary() << endl;
                                                    ^^       ^
```

and similarly for the calls to `getID` and `getName`.

Fixing that should also fix the second error; or that might be caused by the mistyping of `endl`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is pretty self explaining, once you know a bit of C++ terms. The second part (`use '&Employees::getSalary' to create a pointer to member`) will actually confuse you, because the compiler it talking about a totally unrelated C++ capability, that it thinks you may be trying to use.

Let's see:

> 'Employees::getSalary': function call missing argument list

To call a function, you have to specify the argument list, with parenthesis, even if you have no arguments at all!

```
cout << "Employee Salary: " << newStaff[i].getSalary() << end;
```

That is, add a few `()` here and there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use function call `operator ()` (application operator) to call a function

```
function_name()  // call a function named function_name
```

thus:

```
cout << "Employee Id: " << newStaff[i].getID() << endl;
                                            ^^
cout << "Employee Name: " << newStaff[i].getName() << end;
                                                ^^
cout << "Employee Salary: " << newStaff[i].getSalary() << end;
                                                    ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
newStaff[i].getName
```

Needs to be this:

```
newStaff[i].getName()
```

And so on.